# Android Studio Build Error: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/gfprobe-provider.xml'

Tags: java, android-studio, jakarta-mail

I am building a simple android app where the user can send/receive emails. I'm using java mail API. My code runs fine within eclipse but now that I am using Android Studio I am getting a build error.

One answer suggested that I add this to my build.gradle file. But it didn't help

```
android {      
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
      }          
}
```

Here's my build.gradle file

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.javaemailapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation files('/Users/redacted/Downloads/javamail-1.4.4/mail.jar')
    implementation files('/Users/redacted/Downloads/jaf-1.1.1/activation.jar')
}
```

I just want to test and see if the "send" button works in my app but when I click run in Android Studio I get this error:

More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/gfprobe-provider.xml'

Answer (score 0):

Use a more recent version of [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).